# Casting in Generics with related/derived Ts

Tags: c#, generics, casting

```
class BaseItem { }

class DerivedItem : BaseItem { }

interface IInterface<T> where T is BaseItem { }

class RealizedInterface<T> : IInterface<T> { }

RealizedInterface<BaseItem> rb;
RealizedInterface<DerivedItem> rd = new RealizedInterface<DerivedItem>;
```

Is there any way to cast as shown in the next line:

```
rb = rd;
```

Can anyone tell me how to cast `rd` to `rb`?

actually BaseItem itself is a generalized class too but in order to simply the question, did not write it. `class BaseItem<U,K> / DerivedItem<U,K>`

for those who can understand real problem I face is this.

```
IShape<IBaseShape<long>, long> shape;
```

here is an object declared

```
IShape<ITriangle<long>, long> triangle =new Shape<ITriangle<long>,long>(); //Shape derived from IShape

shape = triangle; //here is the problem.
```

where ITriangle Derives from IBaseShape. I really appreciate any help.

RESULT: I decided not to implement out keyword. It does not bring too much value in my case(it is an ongoing project for months and full of generics everywhere). Specifically if you consider implementing setters in an interface with *in* keyword and getters with *out* keyword, plus casting problems created by using generics within an interface decorated with an out keyword made me think about it twice. All in all it could be useful if you started using them from beginning , otherwise it could bring more problems than you might think.

Comment: Language would be a useful additional tag to add. Also, if you want to post code samples, it's usually best to highlight the code and hit the `{}` button.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is Covariance and Contravariance for generic types. You can read up on the topic [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If `IShape` is defined in such a way that you only "retrieve" elements of the first type parameter, then change your definition from `IShape<T, U>` to `IShape<out T, U>` to tell the compiler this, and then everything will work (given a recent enough version of .NET).

If `IShape` is defined in such a way that you can "push" elements of the first type parameter *in* via the interface, then this *cannot* work. If you hide an `IShape<ITriangle...>` as an `IShape<IBaseShape...>` then it will break if you try to "push" an `ISquare` into it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep working with interfaces instead of the actual classes, you can use covariance/contravariance.

Like this:

```
void Main() {   
    RealizedInterface<BaseItem> rb1;
    RealizedInterface<DerivedItem> rd1 = new RealizedInterface<DerivedItem>();
    rb1 = rd1; // doesn't work

    IInterface<BaseItem> rb2;
    IInterface<DerivedItem> rd2 = new RealizedInterface<DerivedItem>();
    rb2 = rd2; // works
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class BaseItem { }

class DerivedItem : BaseItem { }

interface IInterface<out T> where T:  BaseItem { } // Notice the out keyword!

class RealizedInterface<T> : IInterface<T> where T:BaseItem { }
```